# How do I replace all asterisks(*) with spaces on a line of text

Tags: python, regex

I have some data as shown below.

```
| 07:00 |97322.00 | 1411.00 |
| 07:30 |97449.00*| 1411.02*|
| 08:00 |97577.00*| 1411.04*|
| 08:30 |97705.00*| 1411.06*|
```

occasionally the data is tagged with asterisks, and I need to replace the asterisks with spaces so that when it is read by the app I am using it reads a number instead of a string.
Have looked all over, and tried most of the variations on here, and am getting nowhere. This doesn't seem like it should be that difficult.

Answer (score 4):

you can user `.replace()` method.
Ex.

```
str.replace("*"," ")
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try this:

```
import re
s = "| 07:00 |97322.00 | 1411.00 | | 07:30 |97449.00*| 1411.02*| | 08:00 |97577.00*| 1411.04*| | 08:30 |97705.00*| 1411.06*|"
final_string = re.sub("\*", ' ', s)
```

Output:

```
'| 07:00 |97322.00 | 1411.00 | | 07:30 |97449.00 | 1411.02 | | 08:00 |97577.00 | 1411.04 | | 08:30 |97705.00 | 1411.06 |'
```

Comment: It would be better to use `replace()`, rather than `re.sub` as it takes longer than usual String `replace`

Comment: @KaushikNP That is true; however, the OP did tag the question as `regex`.

Comment: Ooops, my mistake. Sorry about that. Didn't notice.

Comment: @KaushikNP No problem. You are correct, however, about the performance of `replace`.

Answer (score 0):

```
string before = "Deleting 11 files.ABC: Total Time = 01:16:30, Remaining Time = 00:00:00";
string after = Regex.Replace( before, @"[*]", "" );
```